# Groups that are not amalgams

Tags: group-theory

It is clear that cyclic groups have the property that they cannot be written in a non-trivial way as an amalgamated free product or as an HNN-extension.

Can someone please provide us examples of torsion-free 2-generated groups having this property? Any comments related to this question are welcome!

[I'm aware of Serre's Theorem 15 in Trees.]

---

**Edit:** The term "in a non-trivial way" means the following.
For an amalgamated free product $G=H*_C K$ it is required $H\ne C\ne K$. For an HNN-extension $G=HNN(H,A,B,t)$ it is required $A\ne H\ne B$.

Comment: Nilo, if you insist that $A\neq H\neq B$ then you're not just allowing $\mathbb{Z}$, but also ascending HNN-extensions, including Thompson's group F (if I recall correctly).  In your comment below my answer, you seemed to want to exclude Thompson's group F.  You can't have it both ways.

Comment: You are definitely right.

Comment: So what's the answer? Are you looking for a two-generator torsion-free group that doesn't split non-trivially in the usual sense, or for one that doesn't split non-trivially in your sense?  Because if the latter, then $\mathbb{Z}^2$ works.

Comment: Thanks, Henry! I missed that completely.
I would be glad to know what is the usual sense... Thanks again.

Comment: I've added an explicit example to my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, your first statement is false for the infinite cyclic group:

$\mathbb{Z}=1*_1$

the trivial HNN extension of the trivial group.  The point is that, by the ideas described in *Trees*, a splitting of a group is the same thing as an action of that group on a tree, and there is an obvious action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on the real line, which is a tree.

A group that does not split is said to have *Property FA*.  There are many constructions of such groups, though some criteria involve torsion, so your torsion-free restriction makes the question more interesting.

One source of examples is given by *random groups*, which can be two-generated.  Dahmani, Guirardel and Przytycki [showed](http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.3854) that random groups have Property FA.

ADDED:

The following is missing some details; the gaps can be filled in from Serre's *Trees* and from Peter Scott's article `The Geometries of 3-manifolds'.  I'll fill in some more details if you ask for them.

Here's an explicit example.  You probably know that *triangle groups*

$T(p,q,r)\cong \langle a,b\mid a^p=b^q=(ab)^r=1)\rangle$

have Property FA. This is quite  easy to see by thinking about actions on trees.  Because they are all of finite order, $a,b$ and $ab$ each have to fix vertices, and the only way this can happen is if they all fix the same vertex.  These groups are 2-generator, but clearly not torsion-free.

Now here's a torsion-free example, which is the fundamental group of a certain Seifert-fibred space.  For details on Seifert-fibred spaces, I recommend Peter Scott's article `The Geometries of 3-manifolds'.

Let $\mathrm{gcd}(p,p')=\mathrm{gcd}(q,q')=\mathrm{gcd}(r,r')=1$. The group in question is

$\Gamma=\langle a,b,z\mid a^p=z^{p'}, b^q=z^{q'}, (ab)^r=z^{r'}, [a,z]=[b,z]=1\rangle~.$

Note that if $\mathrm{gcd}(p',q',r')=1$ then $\Gamma$ is 2-generated; $\Gamma$ is also torsion-free. $\Gamma$ can be written as a non-split central extension

$1\to\langle z\rangle\to \Gamma\to T(p,q,r)\to 1~.$

Suppose that $\Gamma$ acts on a tree $T$.  Then, using some standard lemmas about actions on trees and the fact that it is normal, either $Z=\langle z\rangle$  fixes $T$ pointwise (in which case we are done), or $T$ can be taken to be a line which $z$ translates.

In this latter case, translation distance gives a homomorphism $f:\Gamma\to\mathbb{Z}$ with $f(z)$ non-trivial.  But the existence of this homomorphism implies that

$p'/p+q'/q=r'/r$

which of course won't be true for most choices of parameters.

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with this paper's lingo, I understood that such groups are very likely to have property (FA).
Maybe you can you mention a specific example of a different kind. Thanks.

Comment: What about Thompson's group F? Though that is an infinitely iterated HNN extension.

Comment: @Steve: Sounds interesting, but it seems to me that F is an HNN-extension with infinitely generated base group.

Comment: in the previous comment the word ascending before HNN is missing - sorry.

Comment: @Henry: Many many thanks!

Comment: Nilo: No problem.